# No Loss Found In Tensorflow Model Despite Compiling

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently working on TensorFlow 2.9.2 and I can't seem to get the loss function to work. I've tried creating a model with tf.keras.Sequential() and using model.add for the layers and I've also tried creating a function that creates the model. No matter what I do I always get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [82], line 23
     17 #inputs = keras.Input(shape=(800,66000))
     18 #outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')(inputs)
     19 # If there is a loss passed in `compile`, the regularization
     20 # losses get added to it
     21 model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
---> 23 model.fit(train_x, labels, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=10)
     24 print('My custom loss: ', model.loss_tracker.result().numpy())
     26 #model.summary()
     27 
     28 #loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
     29 #print("Accuracy", accuracy)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File /tmp/__autograph_generated_filejv83ofjv.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 891, in train_step
        self._validate_target_and_loss(y, loss)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 857, in _validate_target_and_loss
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: No loss found. You may have forgotten to provide a `loss` argument in the `compile()` method.
```

Attempt Number 1:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense
import keras
from keras import losses 
from keras import optimizers 
from keras import metrics 
def create_model(): 
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(65000/train.shape[0], input_shape=(65000,)),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(3,activation='sigmoid'),
    ])
    
    #model.add_loss(tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())


    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error',  optimizer = 'sgd', metrics = [metrics.categorical_accuracy])
    
    return model

model = create_model()
model.fit(train_x, labels, epochs=10)
```

Attempt Number 2:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense
import keras
from keras import losses 
from keras import optimizers 
from keras import metrics 
model =tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
model.fit(train_x, labels, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=10)
print('My custom loss: ', model.loss_tracker.result().numpy())
```

Both attempts lead me to the ValueError that no loss is found.

Here are my version information:

```
tensorflow version 2.9.2
numpy version 1.23.4
pandas version 1.5.0
keras version 2.9.0
python Version:- 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) 
[GCC 9.4.0]
```

I am running on a paperspace.com Jupyter Notebook. I have tried creating another Notebook on a different graphics card and still no luck.

Output of !jupyter--version:

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.5.0
ipykernel        : 6.16.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.2
jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
jupyter_core     : 5.1.5
jupyter_server   : 1.23.5
jupyterlab       : 3.4.6
nbclient         : 0.7.2
nbconvert        : 7.2.9
nbformat         : 5.7.3
notebook         : 6.5.2
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.8.1
```

Comment: Please always include errors in verbatim form, a traceback in this case.

Comment: Added full error! Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to the computed loss value for the model output and labels being `None`.

Perhaps it is not your case, but it can come up when the model has no outputs for some reason (`len(model.outputs) == 0`). You could check the model architecture with `model.summary()` or the outputs with `model.outputs` just to verify that the structure is correct and matches the structure of the `labels`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class instead of the loss's name:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


# ...

model.compile(
  loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
  optimizer='sgd',
  metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy]
)

# ...
```

Source: https://keras.io/api/losses/